# How do you make all dataframes in a list have the same number of columns?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to make all dataframes in a list have the same number of columns.

Create a list of 3 dataframes, but the 2nd has 1 extra column.

```
    my_data<- 
        list(    data.frame(
         V1= c(1,1,1,1,1),
         V2= c(2,2,2,2,2),
         V3= c(3,3,3,3,3),
         V4= c(4,4,4,4,4),
         V5= c(5,5,5,5,5)), 
       data.frame(
         V1= c(1,1,1,1,1),
         V2= c(2,2,2,2,2),
         V3= c(3,3,3,3,3),
         V4= c(4,4,4,4,4),
         V5= c(5,5,5,5,5),
         V6= c(6,6,6,6,6)),
       data.frame(
         V1= c(1,1,1,1,1),
         V2= c(2,2,2,2,2),
         V3= c(3,3,3,3,3),
         V4= c(4,4,4,4,4),
         V5= c(5,5,5,5,5))
```

manual removal of column: if df[[2]] has > 5 columns, remove the 6th

```
if (ncol(my_data[[2]])>5) {
my_data[[2]][,-6]
}
```

But why doesn't the same logic doesn't work when looping it through the list?

```
for (i in 1:length(my_data)) {

 if (ncol(my_data[[i]])>5) {
my_data[[i]][,-6]
 } 
}
```

Comment: To answer your actual question: your logic works perfectly fine. You just have to assign the result within the `if` clause.  Like this: `my_data[[i]] <- my_data[[i]][,-6]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic works just fine. When you are iterating through the loop, you have to assign the updated frame back to that element of the list.

Simply replace:

```
my_data[[i]][,-6]
```

with

```
my_data[[i]]<-my_data[[i]][,-6]
```

within the `if` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Get the `min`imum number of columns from all the data.frames in the list and then use that information in the `for` loop, do the assignment (`<-`) to update the data.frame elements in the `list`

```
n <- min(sapply(my_data, ncol))
for(i in seq_along(my_data)) my_data[[i]] <- my_data[[i]][seq_len(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the columns with the same names (no matter of the order), then you get the common column names, and select those:

```r
selected_cols <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(my_data, names))
my_data <- lapply(my_data, function(x) x[selected_cols, ])
```